# Reading the value of an Angular variable from a DOM attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, scope

I am assigning an Angular variable to a class and I am trying to work with its actual value in the Javascript but I can't seem to get it displayed correctly and get instead its Angular {{}} format.
Here in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7z4wmnjj/42/) link, I am trying to display it as follow:

```
<script> var test = angular.element(document.getElementById("test"))[0]; 
         alert(test.className);   </script>
```

Although in the console.log the class value is displayed correctly, if I try working with it in the JS I seem to get the unresolved Angular format instead of the value "en" as defined below:

```
function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.site = {
        language: "en"
    };

    $scope.display = function (text) {
        alert(text);
    };
}
```

I've seen that most questions regarding passing Angular vars to JS mention the ng-click attribute but it seems irrelevant in my case. 
Hence, I would appreciate any insight on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: why are you trying to do it this way?  angular two way bindings are in place so that you don't have to go rooting around in the document to find values.  You seem to be trying to avoid using angular here, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: and for the record, that's exactly the correct behavior for the code as written.  The `<script>` is executed on page load, before angular has done any parsing of the DOM.  "Passing Angular vars to JS" doesn't even make any sense, since Angular is a framework written in JS, it's not a competing language.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Well this is just a simplified scenario, the actual problem is a little more complicated. The thing is I have an embedded js library that takes in a language parameter (for example <script data-languge="en"/>) and returns a DOM object based on it. Unfortunately, this language parameter is defined an Angular variable that is why I m trying to find a workaround.

Comment: Not enough known about source of language if it's not `en`

Comment: this isn't really something that you can use angular for;  as I stated previously, these `<script>` tags are going to run before angular has had a chance to bootstrap.   If using angular is **the only way** to determine this property, you would have to rig the loading of the script into a directive that fires after angular has bootstrapped.